# Do you need to train your ml model equal no. of times before and after fine tuning while using transfer learning?

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, artificial-intelligence

I'm trying to make a model that can classify 7 different denomination of bank note. I'm using VGG19 as a convolution base. I've a dataset of more than 10000 images with each category containing more than 1k. How many layers should I add after convolution base? and also what would be the size of each layer.

Answer (score 0):

This question is too vague. Choosing right architecture is not a simple task. It depends on your domain. Using ready-made architectures you're prone to overshoot the problem. Capacity of such networks might be an overkill. You'll get nice low entropy in your net but it will overfit as crazy. Rule of thumb: start with smaller nets, slowly build up and compare your metrics.

There's similar thread [here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/20222/how-to-decide-neural-network-architecture).

There's ongoing research regarding `Network Architecture Search`. Afaik the only available solution is Google's Auto-ML. Metaheuristics-based `NAS` is still in its infancy and won't be widely used for some time.

Most popular open-source `NAS` is [AutoKeras](https://autokeras.com/).